# Replace the contents of a specific tab in a dojo/dijit TabContainer?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to change the class of one of the the tabs - that panel will change from a subclassed `ContentPane` widget to a subclassed `BorderLayout` widget.

At the very least I can probably delete the child from the `TabContainer` and then insert a new child with the same tab title at the position of that destroyed tab. But is there a legitimate shortcut to simply *replace* the backing control without invalidating the tabs?

(Dojo 1.8 - programmatic instantiation of widgets)

Comment: Once you call `addChild(child)`, you pass a `var` of the type `ContentPane` rigth? Wouldn't it be possible, to override that `var` wih the new `BorderContainer`?

Comment: well, I can change that var - but that won't change whatever TabContainer-internal vars are pointing at the old ContentPane...  I need to tell the container that its contents are changing.  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: well, than i thing this migth simply not be possible. As you already said, the `TabContainer` does not provide a `replace` Method or anything similar. But it should be possible to do a nasty workaroud doing `yourContentPane.set('content', yourBorderContainer.domNode);` or sth. like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding tab via `dijit/layout/ContentPane` add it as `dijit/layout/StackPane`. Then use StackPane's methods `addChild(widget)`, `removeChild(widget)`and/or `selectChild(widget)`:

```
var tab1 = registry.byId("tab1"); // dijit/layout/StackContainer

var bc = new BorderContainer();
var cp1 = new ContentPane({
    content: "content pane 1",
    region: "top"        
});
var cp2 = new ContentPane({
    content: "content pane 2",
    region: "center"
});
bc.addChild(cp1);
bc.addChild(cp2);

tab1.addChild(bc);
tab1.selectChild(bc);
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/szCb4/

Comment: Does exactly what I asked, thanks (Just 1 note for others: this requires knowing that you're going to be swapping a particular tab, and preparing ahead of time - would still be curious if there's a post-hoc method too.  But this works fine for now!)